# SVGs suddenly disappeared on production site w/ no changes made

Tags: javascript, html, svg, gruntjs

Suddenly, all SVGs have disappeared from my site. The issue is quite perplexing, as no changes have been made to code, database, or files since the graphics last displayed as normal.

[Missing icons in our nav bar and on home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKaaL.png)

I've even tried restoring to this previous point, and the icons are still missing. I'm quite perplexed.

Here's the code before, where the SVG is inject within an  tag:

```html
<i class="icon-serenova-shine_bright-logo" style="background-image: none;"><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 367 94" style="enable-background:new 0 0 367 94;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css"> .someStyle{fill:#fff;}</style>
    <g><path class="somePath"></path></g> 
    <g><path class="etc"></path></g> 
  </svg>
</i>
```

And now, the  tags are empty:

```html
<i class="icon-serenova-shine_bright-logo" data-grunticon-embed=""></i>
```

The icons are placed with a Grunt task/tool called Grunticon.

For easier reference, here is the production site: https://www.serenova.com
And the staging site where SVGs are still displaying [is here](https://staging.serenova.com/).

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't match your site - possibly a browser issue? Which browser "fails" - hmm, seems only Firefox works with that site

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, thanks for your response. All browsers fail for me, including Firefox: http://prntscr.com/iu14b3 

If you are looking at the second link, that's the staging site, where there are a number of changes awaiting deployment and thus, it looks different.

Thanks!

Comment: When I open to see a code, there are no icon. I think your icons are added after page load with some javascript code. Check this and fix it. HTML code is not the same at both sites.

Comment: Well, I can't see what isn't there, but I can see the difference between firefox and other browsers - on the non-staging page (i.e. `serenova` to the left of `products` and `cxengage` above `for brighter agent experiences` ... these are present in Firefox, absent in other browsers

Comment: let me rephrase that ... they **were** present in firefox, and have now gone as well ... how odd

Comment: What happend in the last few days is the update to Firefox 59. And part of that was a change to the security policy for data urls:

[Blocking Top-Level Navigations to data URLs for Firefox 59](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/11/27/blocking-top-level-navigations-data-urls-firefox-59/)

Your post is a bit obscure how exactly you are inserting the svg content, but I can see that there is a stylesheet `icons.data.svg.css` that contains all icons as data urls.